# integration on real domain only!

Tags: integral-equations

i am trying to integrate a real valued function. For some reason, *Mathematica* gives an answer in the complex domain. I'd be grateful for your answers.

Here is the integral:

```
Integrate[(-(Cos[b*s] - (2*Sin[b*s]*(a*D - b*C))/(a^2 + b^2))/E^(a*s))^2, {s, 1, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[s, Reals]]
```

*Mathematica* produces the following:

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[1/4 
>     (1/a + 1/(2 a - 2 I b) + 1/(2 a + 2 I b) + (-1 + E^(-2 a))/a + 
>     (-1 + E^(-2 (a + I b)))/(2 (a + I b)) + 
>     (-1 + E^(-2 a + 2 I b))/(2 a - 2 I b) - 
>     (2 (b C - a D)^2 E^(-2 (a + I b)) (-2 b^2 E^(2 I b) + 
>       a^2 (-1 + E^(2 I b))^2 + I a b (-1 + E^(4 I b))))/(a (a^2 + b^2)^3) + 
>     (4 (b C - a D) E^(-2 a) (b Cos[2 b] + a Sin[2 b]))/(a^2 + b^2)^2), 
>   Abs[Im[b]] < Re[a] && Re[a] > 0]
> ```

Comment: You've only told *Mathematica* that s is real. What about a, b, c? Also you should refrain from using capitalized letters as variables, as D is an internal function.

Comment: Also, what happens if $b \in \mathbb{R}$, what do the conditions then say? (I don't mean programmatically, which can be done using [`Reduce`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0dqugjdgcya-k7rt3), but by hand.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: nothing changes though!

Answer (score 8):

Your `s` lives on the ray [1,infinity). `Integrate` can kinda figure out `s` is real. Tell it about the other variables and then we'll proceed from there.

```
i1 = 
 Integrate[(-(Cos[b*s] - (2*Sin[b*s]*(a*d - b*c))/(a^2 + b^2))/
     E^(a*s))^2, {s, 1, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> {Element[{b, c, d}, Reals], a > 0}]

(* Out[152]= 1/4 (1/a + 1/(2 a - 2 I b) + 1/(
   2 a + 2 I b) + (-1 + E^(-2 a))/a + (-1 + E^(-2 (a + I b)))/(
   2 (a + I b)) + (-1 + E^(-2 a + 2 I b))/(2 a - 2 I b) - (1/(
   a (a^2 + b^2)^3))
   2 (b c - a d)^2 E^(-2 (a + I b)) (-2 b^2 E^(2 I b) + 
      a^2 (-1 + E^(2 I b))^2 + I a b (-1 + E^(4 I b))) + (
   4 (b c - a d) E^(-2 a) (b Cos[2 b] + a Sin[2 b]))/(a^2 + b^2)^2) *)
```

`ComplexExpand` is good about separating real and imaginary parts under the assumption that variables are real-valued. It is not good at conciseness, so follow up with `Simplify` and hope for the best. Or trust that I checked this first.

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[i1]]

(* Out[155]= (1/(4 a (a^2 + 
   b^2)^3))E^(-2 a) ((a^2 + b^2) (a^4 + b^4 + 4 b^2 c^2 - 8 a b c d + 
      2 a^2 (b^2 + 2 d^2)) + 
   a (a^5 + 4 b^4 c + 4 a^2 b c (b + 2 d) + 
      a b^2 (b^2 - 4 c^2 - 4 b d) + 2 a^3 (b^2 - 2 b d - 2 d^2)) Cos[
     2 b] - a (b^5 - 4 a^3 b c - 4 b^3 c^2 - 4 a b^2 c (b - 2 d) + 
      a^4 (b + 4 d) + 2 a^2 b (b^2 + 2 b d - 2 d^2)) Sin[2 b]) *)
```

Comment: {Element[{b, c, d}, Reals], a > 0}
why dont we just write Element{a,b,c,d}, Reals ?

Comment: That extra was just to get rid of the `Conditional` result: the positivity is to get convergence.

Comment: thank you so much, I've just started using mathematica, I greatly appreciate your help.